# athk10 Linux mint killer wireless ac 1535 installation

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I am trying to install the killer wireless 1535 ac on Linux Mint.

I am running kernel 4.2-025 on Linux mint 17.3 rosa.

These are the instructions I have found from googling but I tried to make them work, without any success.

According to the killer wireless website, you need to update the firmware, which I did following this advice: http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-Linux

-- but using the latest instruction from here: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath10k/firmware

Since the killer wireless instruction are dated (as I have found people saying on different attempts to solve their own installation problems), according to what I have gathered I downloaded the latest firmware binary and copied it as instructed like this:

```
cp firmware-5.bin_10.2.4.70.17-2 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
```

and so far nothing has changed wireless still doesn't show as an option for internet

I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Is it a PCI or USB adapter?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: `sudo modprobe ath10k_pci && dmesg | grep ath`

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:180 kmod_module_parse_depline() ctx=0x55a9457b8010 path=/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko error=No such file or directory
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:180 kmod_module_parse_depline() ctx=0x55a9457b8010 path=/lib/modules/4.2.0-25-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko error=No such file or directory
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ath10k_pci': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)

Comment: It appears that you attempted to compile a driver from source code and that it went badly. I will propose another solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please download this file to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.3/backports-4.3-1.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-4.3.1
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

You will have built the driver for your current kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later kernel version, also known as linux-image, after the requested reboot, re-compile:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-4.3.1
make clean
make defconfig-ath10k
make
sudo make install
```

Please retain the files and these instructions for that time.

This device also requires firmware. Please download this package to your desktop: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb

Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: now in network settings wireless is there , however it does not pick up anything or allow to connect to any wireless network

Comment: [link](http://www.filedropper.com/file_202) here is an output file after running   dkms status; dmesg | grep ath10k

Comment: Is this a laptop? Is the switch or key combination set to enable the wireless radio? `rfkill list all` Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep ath` Your output doesn't reveal much and we'd prefer to see logs posted at: http://pastebin.com/ and give us the link.

Comment: of course its a laptop, i dont think desktops have wireless? no problem i will post to pastebin from now on

0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
dmesg | grep ath gives :

Comment: Of course desktops can have wireless; USB or even PCI: http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-Linksys-WMP54G-Wireless-G-PCI-Adapter/dp/B000085BD8

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k0zZbwFC

Comment: dmesg | grep ath gives the pastebin result

Comment: All the "modules linked in" entries usually follow a crash, or near crack of something in the system. I suggest you check `dmesg | less` and use the arrow keys to scroll back and forth to see what happens just before those lines. Google the error or ask a separate question here and try to get that resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34757/discussion-between-chili555-and-hopjopper).

Comment: @chili555 - why do you have to introduce such meaningless concepts as "download to desktop" ? Why can't you just say download?

Comment: @400theCat  Because not everyone has downloads from, for example, Firefox, set to the Downloads folder. Also, if the terminal is not already in the directory ~/Downloads, then the installation fails. The point is, unless we specify where the package is to be downloaded and to be installed, then we are guessing and prone to error. In this context, it is hardly meaningless.