# backports error while trying to get killer wireless-ac 1535 working in linux mint 17.3

Tags: backports

I just got a new laptop with a killer wireless-ac 1535. After installing linux mint 17.3 I cannot use the wifi.

I found some information about this here:

[athk10 linux mint killer wireless ac 1535 installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257019/athk10-linux-mint-killer-wireless-ac-1535-installation)

and here:

http://www.killernetworking.com/support/knowledge-base/17-linux

However I am having trouble getting the backports to build, I get the following error:

```
make[5]: `conf' is up to date.
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
boolean symbol HWMON tested for 'm'? test forced to 'n'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
Building backport-include/backport/autoconf.h ... done.
  CC [M]  /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/main.o
  CC [M]  /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.14.o
  CC [M]  /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.15.o
  CC [M]  /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.17.o
  CC [M]  /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.18.o
In file included from include/linux/if_vlan.h:15:0,
                 from /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/backport-include/linux/if_vlan.h:3,
                 from /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.18.c:11:
/home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/backport-include/linux/netdevice.h:85:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct pcpu_sw_netstats’
 struct pcpu_sw_netstats {
        ^
In file included from /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/backport-include/linux/netdevice.h:3:0,
                 from include/linux/if_vlan.h:15,
                 from /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/backport-include/linux/if_vlan.h:3,
                 from /home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.18.c:11:
include/linux/netdevice.h:1706:8: note: originally defined here
 struct pcpu_sw_netstats {
        ^
make[6]: *** [/home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat/backport-3.18.o] Error 1
make[5]: *** [/home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1/compat] Error 2
make[4]: *** [_module_/home/moagstar/Desktop/backports-4.3-1] Error 2
make[3]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Does anyone have any clue why this error might be occuring?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem in case anybody else encouters this. When I comment out the definition for struct pcpu_sw_netstats in netdevice.h I could get the backports to build. I also had to chmod a+x a number of files for the make install to work correctly. But it did work in the end, the wifi is now working perfectly!