# Wifi is not working in kali-linux

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot, iwlwifi

I dual-boot kali linux with windows 10. After installation wifi is not working. I can run internet by using USB modem. It's surprising because during its installation i provided all the required firmwares for wifi and ethernet which installer was asking. The rest of the firmwares which were still missing, i copied them to `/lib/firmware` after installation. I've `Intel Dual-Band Wireless AC-3165` wifi adapter.

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: please add the output of `uname -a`

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: can you add output of `rfkill list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the firmware from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) or from [here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html)

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-7265-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
```

copy it to your /lib/firmware

```
cp iwlwifi* /lib/firmware
```

install the required package `build-essential` and `linux-headers` :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Run `apt-cache search linux-headers` then install it

Download and compile backports:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2016/03/24/backports-20160324.tar.gz
tar xvf backports-20160324
cd backports-20160324
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
make install
```

Reboot

**Edit**

Open the `sources.list`  file:

```
apt edit-sources
```

Choose the text editor e,g : `1` (`nano`) add the following line ( verify it):

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Save it then run the following commands :

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

Then install the appropriate `linux-headers`
e,g:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-amd64
apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-kali1-amd64
```

Reboot your system , from the advanced option **Boot Kali-linux with the `4.8.0` kernel version** then compile backports .

**Update**

[Blacklist `acer_wmi` solve the problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/327558/153195)

Comment: It worked. It is downloading  new upgrade packages. I'm sure rest of the command-lines will work after upgrade is done.

Comment: @user334283 after editing the `sources.list` are you able to found/ install the `linux-headers` ?

Comment: I'm able to install linux-headers with a little search on internet. Now  I'm supposed to `download and compile backports` but each time I enter the command-line `make` after extracting,  it displays errors as shown in the screenshot. See above. I think I'm on the last step of your answer.

Comment: @user334283 i edit my answer it should work for you

Comment: @user334283 Run `apt-cache search linux-headers`  and `apt-cache policy linux-headers*` then upload the output here: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k5cjJ1Vy

Comment: @user334283 `apt-cache policy linux-headers*` to get all installed linux-headers

Comment: This is the output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers*` http://pastebin.com/PwUGBXd9

Comment: Is this question helpful http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/288821/192349 ?

Comment: @user334283 No , it is not helpful ,  required some others details . try to boot the 4.8 kernel then run : `apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-kali1-all-amd64` then try to compile

Comment: This is the error i was talking about. http://pastebin.com/jsnKt816 . I maybe new to shell commands but that's not tough to guess that these are compile-time errors. Codes of backports have errors.

Comment: I fixed it. See my answer. Backports were never really a problem. Backports are not even required for the latest kernel module.

Answer (score 3):

Your Terminal output `rfkill list` shows the following issue:

The GNU/Linux kernel is loading the `acer_wmi` kernel module, even though you are NOT using Acer hardware.

Both the `acer_wmi` and `intel_wmi` kernel modules are running at the same time, causing a conflict and causing the wireless adapter to get deactivated by the `acer_wmi` kernel module.

However, you are using an intel adapter, not an NIC by Acer.

So the `acer_wmi` module needs to be blacklisted (= prevent it from starting during boot).

Please copy-paste the following command into the Terminal and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

`gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Using the gedit editor, please scroll down and ADD the following configuration line into the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist acer_wmi
```

Using the gedit editor, SAVE the change to the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file.

Then REBOOT and retest wireless. This blacklist operation should make
the change permanent, even after rebooting.

This should force the Linux kernel to stop loading the `acer_wmi` module,
which is probably causing the kernel to soft block your wireless adapter.

The acer-wireless interface is an invalid wireless interface on your
computer, because you are not using ACER hardware.

Answer (score 1):

No need for anything complex, you can install the firmware package directly with apt.

The commands to install the firmware are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
```

The commands to reload the driver are:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: output of your commandlines: `root@defalt:~# sudo apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
root@defalt:~# sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-iwlwifi is already the newest version (20160712-0kali1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@defalt:~# sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.
root@defalt:~# sudo modprobe iwlwifi`

Comment: By the sounds of the errors the wifi interface is up already, try a reboot or ifdown wlan0 before unloading the module