# Wifi kept being disabled kali windows dual boot

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, dual-boot

My wifi kept being disabled whenever i m trying to boot into kali it just kept saying my wifi is turned off and whenever i press the function key it just toggle the airplane mode and only when I am in windows i can use wifi again please help

I have also tried no pressing function key if so the wifi will keep toggling between on and off and I have searched a lot online solutions none of them works for me also in bios there is no option for me to set wireless because I am using a hp bios, and for some reason no one online can use hp to enable wireless in bios either.

I have tried to reboot it several times and BIOS didn't have the setting of wireless which is frustrating I am using a HP OMEN laptop!

(new update)

When I boot into kali I notice some error message poped up quickly and so I decide to film it to see what is that and here is what it said

```
/dev/sda8: ckean 322608/1222992 files, 2061280/4882432 blocks
[    2.126107] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x9cf
[    2.252385] kvm: disabled by bios
[    2.279672] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.GFXO.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, 
AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831.psargs-359)
[    2.279678] ACPI Error: Method parse\execution failed [\_SC_.PCIO.PEGO.DD
02._BCL] (Node ffff9a250e8fb0a0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/psparese-543)
[    2.383886] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUNO: 10ecc0 fffffff (1e40822c)
[    2.391391] kvm: disabled by bios
[    3.682080] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid
[    3.682117] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to flat panel table invalid
```

I tried enabling virtualization technology in bios, then the error message just left

```
[    2.126107] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0x9cf
```

but then the wireless hardware is disabled and even when I boot back into windows nothing I do can turn back on wireless capacity. So I have disabled virtualization technology now to let me connect to wifi and update this question

Comment: Someone please before voting -1 and make this question even more unreachable tell me what I did wrong why do you vote me -1?

Comment: Show the output of **rfkill list all**

Comment: The output is 0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN soft blocked yes hard blocked no 1: phy0: wireless lan both no and 2: hci0: bluetooth both no as well i unblocked all and now all is unblocked but still flashing the wifi sorry i m on phone now

Comment: during installation kali didnt ask anything about wireless adapters or firmware But I don't know how to check if my firmware is missing

Comment: My computer is using Intel Dual-Band Wireless AC-7260 adapter

Comment: Thank You So Much I cannot know express my thanks to you I saw the other post you answer about the acer wireless lan and intel and after I followed your instruction Wala I am connect to wifi as usual Thank You!!!!!! @defalt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was provided in *@defalt's* answer to ["Wifi is not working in kali-linux"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321464/wifi-is-not-working-in-kali-linux/327558#327558).

Blacklisting `acer_wmi` module solved the problem.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it clearer. You should mark your own answer as accepted.